# CSS Override background without changing or restoring background image

Tags: css

When I try in stylish(chrome) 
`*{ 
      background : black !important 
}` 
all the background images are overridden,

I was wondering if there is a way to restore the background images or keep them intact.

Thanks

Comment: add `z-index: -1`

Answer (score 2):

> Use `background-color` instead of `background`

```
*:not([background-image]) {
  background-color:black!important;
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqy1uodNithL90ttojytSP2imO4RC1y3qlm_ebZdRmNWh_8juV9Q');
}

*:not([background-image]) {
  background-color:black!important;
}
```

```html
<div>I am Test</div>
<div class="bg">I am Test2</div>
```

Comment: Hi,

many thanks for the reply, but at many background: white !important is encountered, is there a way to override them too ?

Comment: You can use *:not([background-image]),*:not([background:'white']){ ...} but this is hard because priority selector must be less down of * selector.if help you upvote and mark please.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their response,
I was trying to create a global css to inject in the pages for dark background, but I guess I will have to write separate css for the frequently visited sites ( as they have diff layout ) and a global css for another sites,

Comment: Just using `background-color` instead of `background` is so helpful, but facepalm moment - code I'm working on literally is using hundreds of instances of `background:` and just defines the color!